# using exec() with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript

1. user enters 2 strings
2. use a regular expression to search for the second string within the
   first string.

Those are my directions to follow. I was not told what to do with the search results so I decided to use the exec() method to display the results.

[jsfiddle code example](http://jsfiddle.net/480oye76/)

My code does not display any results.

**html:**

```
<div id="string_search">
    <h3>Requirement #1</h3>
    <p>Enter a string in the first box. <br>
    Enter a search term in the second box.<br>
    Click the button to find the term.</p>

    <textarea id="user_string" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter string (text) here."></textarea>
    <form>
    Enter Search Term:<input type="text" id="search_term" size="45"><br>
    <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" onclick="SearchString()"><br>
    </form>
    <textarea id="search_results" placeholder="Results here..." rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
function SearchString(){
    var user_string = document.getElementById("user_string").innerHTML;
    var search_term = document.getElementById("search_term").value;
    // regex to find all instances of search term
    var re = new RegExp(search_term,"gi");
    //use exec() to return matched text
    var result = re.exec(user_string);
    //display results in textarea "search_results"
    document.getElementById("search_results").innerHTML = result;
}
```

I am not getting console errors, is my code not functional? maybe there's a spelling error im not seeing or similar. Been staring at this for awhile,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine, you had some mistakes.

http://jsfiddle.net/6p3odux1/

```
function SearchString(){
    var user_string = document.getElementById("user_string").value;
    var search_term = document.getElementById("search_term").value;
    // regex to find all instances of search term
    var re = new RegExp(search_term,"gi");
    //use exec() to return matched text
    var result = re.exec(user_string);
    //display results in textarea "search_results"
    document.getElementById("search_results").innerHTML = result;
}
```

any input element you should use `value` not `innerHTML`